# Studies on breakdown of various costs associated with a Software project

Tags: testing, pricing, case-studies

I am looking for links and advice on studies done on the breakdown of costs associated with Software development.

In particular I am looking on what percentage of effort is testing vs programming, and how it changed with team sizes, duration of project and similar factors.

Comment: I think the question should be in Project Management(http://pm.stackexchange.com/) and may be later in Software Development Process (http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30495/software-development-process).

Comment: This question was closed during the [STCI \[software-engineering\] cleanup](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/3263/structured-tag-cleanup-software-engineering).

Answer (score 2):

Start here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COCOMO

The COCOMO model is simply based on a statistical analysis of a large number of projects.

The book provides the details of how the various ratios were derived.